# Should I instantiate collection field on declaration?

Tags: java, refactoring

Is it good practice to instantiate collection field on declaration? For example:

```
class A {
    private List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<String> getList() {
        return list;  
    }

    public setList(List<String> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
}
```

The reason why I need it is avoiding of checking for null like this:

```
if (a.getList() != null)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is better to avoid having a `null` value where possible. You can also make the field `final` so you know it will never be `null`  There are annotations which allow you to trace the value can't be null.

```
private final List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

@NotNull
public List<String> getList() {
    return list;  
}
```

if you do this later

```
if (a.getList() != null) // your IDE can tell you this is always true.
```

Answer (score 1):

Opinions vary, but in this case I'd argue definitely **yes**: empty collections are far clearer and purer than nullable *and* empty-able collections.

Initialising there also means you could make the field `final` which confers some benefits, though here you'd have to make your `setList()` instead call `clear()` and `addAll()` the new items. So perhaps not much benefit in *that alone* here but in other cases it has advantages...

Answer (score 0):

I believe a better place to initiate your objects is the **Constructor** of your class.
A comprehensive explanation : [Should I instantiate instance variables on declaration or in the constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1994232/2119902)

[Instantiating object in a constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9282784/2119902)

Comment: Care to elaborate why this would be better?

Comment: @Nfear Please refer to this answer  [Instantiating object in a constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9282784/2119902)

Comment: I see. So for cases where the arraylist won't be used. The initialization can be avoided to spare memory.

Answer (score 0):

With the specific code you showed, `setList()` can set a `null` value, so you cannot remove the null checks. However I would recommend you change the setter to 1) reject null values, or 2) set `Collections.emptyList()` instead of null, or 3) set a new `ArrayList` or `LinkedList` instead of `null`.
null values are always a pain to deal with, and this is even worse with collections. Many best practices recommend to forbid null collections. And I woleheartedly agree.

Changing such behaviour mean you need to look at all call sites for `getList ()` and check such change will not break it. If it does, then you need to change the solution or adapt client code.