# Java: Initialiasing objects inside or outside the constructor?

Tags: java, constructor, initialization

I am interested in understanding whether there is any difference between initialising an object inside or outside the constructor

```
public class HTMLTable {
int value1;
Scanner user_input;

  public HTMLTable () {
    user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
    value = user_input.next();
  }
}
```

Instead of:

```
public class HTMLTable {
int value1;
Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);

  public HTMLTable () {
    value = user_input.next();
  }
}
```

Can someone explain?

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918578/should-i-initialize-variable-within-constructor-or-outside-constructor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no difference: the compiler will move any *outside initialization* within the constructor.

See Java for a Nutshell, section [3.2.4: Field Defaults and Initializers](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_02.htm).

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference. Compiler would move initialization code (like in 2nd example) into constructor body anyway. Chose this or that variant depending on readability of the code.