# Java class, what is the best pratice for setting values in class constructor?

Tags: java

For example I have a class

class1:

```
public class car{
private Color carColor;
public car(Color carColor)
{
    this.carColor = carColor;
}

public void setColor(Color carColor)
{
    this.carColor = carColor;
}
}
```

class2:

```
public class car{
    private Color carColor;
    public car(Color carColor)
    {
        setColor(carColor);
    }

    public void setColor(Color carColor)
    {
        this.carColor = carColor;
    }
}
```

Which Constructor would be the best practice in java coding and why?

Comment: Both constructors are semantically the same. Best practice? I would say none, make it as you want.

Comment: I generally try to avoid using non-private methods inside constructor since they can be overriden in derived class and used in `super` constructor instead of original method.

Comment: Follow java naming convention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use the first option, since you can have a validation within `setColor()`.

Comment: Maybe you should apply that validation when instantiating the object too =\ (which leads to debate...)

Answer (score 2):

The first way is more intuitive and shows up more often.   i.e. like so:

```
public car(Color carColor)
{
    this.carColor = carColor;
}
```

It is more readable. But both are equal so it's a style issue.

See this too: [Should I initialize variable within constructor or outside constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918578/should-i-initialize-variable-within-constructor-or-outside-constructor)

Comment: This should be a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza why? It's easy question that may require simple answer...

Comment: Because this is a personal opinion rather than an answer supported by facts, references, or specific expertise.

Answer (score 1):

Class1 I suppose. Getter and Setter methods are usually necessary but it is the job of the Constructor to initialize variables of that object.

Answer (score 1):

If I have many calculations that should be done on the variable before setting it, I would do it in a separate method, otherwise, I would choose the first approach.

```
public car(Color carColor)
{
    setColor(carColor);
}

public void setColor(Color carColor)
{
    Color res;
    //Many calculations
    //..
    //..
    //finally 
    this.carColor = res;
}
```

But if I only want to set it, I would simple:

```
public car(Color carColor)
{
    this.carColor = carColor;
}
```