# Difference between assign values for the variables of a class

Tags: class, oop, variables, object, constructor

What is the difference between below 2 ways of assigning values for variables of a class.

```
Class A{
 Private Variable v = someValue;
}
```

vs

```
Class A{
    private Variable v;

    //constructor
    public A(){
        this.v = someValue;
    }
}
```

Can someone please explain?

Comment: In which languages is the first option a valid syntax? In vb.net it is not I think?

Comment: @DrDonut In Java, it is valid. And Probably there are some other too.

Comment: See this related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3919225/1274820

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no real difference from a code execution point of view.

As a previous answer says, I prefer declaring the variable outside of the constructor; for example:

```
public class A {
    private int aValue = 100;
}
```

Instead of

```
public class A {
    private int aValue;
    public A() {
       this.aValue = 100;
    }
}
```

The reason being that if you have multiple constructors, you do not have to keep writing `this.aValue = 100;` and you are unable to "forget" to initialize the variable in a constructor.

As others have said however, there are times when it is better to initialize the variable in the constructor.

- If it will change based on values passed to it via the constructor, obviously initialize it there.
- If the variable you are initializing may throw an error and you need to use `try` / `catch` - it is clearly better to initialize it in the constructor
- If you are working on a team that uses a specific coding standard and they require you to initialize your variables in the constructor, you should do so.

Given freedom and none of the above, I still declare it at the top - makes it much easier to find all of your variables in one place (in my experience).

See this duplicate answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3919225/1274820

Answer (score 1):

> What is the difference between below 2 ways of assigning values for
>   variables of a class.

Generally nothing, but ...
class constructor is an entry point when creating a new instance, so all assignments should be done there for readability and maintainability.

When you want create a new instance you start reading a source code at the constructor. Here is an example. All informations about new instance are in one proper place.

```
public class C {
    private int aValue;
    private int bValue;
    private int cValue;
    private int dValue;

    public C(int a, int b) {
       this.aValue = a;
       this.bValue = b;
       this.cValue = a * b;
       this.dValue = 1000;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the MSIL of this class:

```
namespace Demo
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        private string str = "hello world";
        private int b;

        public MyClass(int b)
        {
            this.b = b;
        }
    }
}



.method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
        instance void  .ctor(int32 b) cil managed
{
  // Code size       25 (0x19)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  ldarg.0
  IL_0001:  ldstr      "hello world"
  IL_0006:  stfld      string Demo.MyClass::str  <---- RIGHT HERE
  IL_000b:  ldarg.0
  IL_000c:  call       instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
  IL_0011:  ldarg.0
  IL_0012:  ldarg.1
  IL_0013:  stfld      int32 Demo.MyClass::b
  IL_0018:  ret
} // end of method MyClass::.ctor
```

You can see that the constructor is "injected" with the assignment of `this.str = "hello world"`.

So once your code is compiled, there is no difference what so ever. Yet, there are quite a few good reasons why you should not do it (user1274820's answer has some them)