# Vaadin ComboBox don't allow me to click

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-elements

I'm using Vaadin ComboBox in my Project and now I've got a new problem, which don't allows me to open the Combo's list after clicking on the ComboBox or on the DropDown Icon! 
I can type in the ComboBox and with arrow keys from the keyboard I can open the ComboBox list but not with clicking.
I found out, when I hold my mouse pointer in a specific area top on the ComboBox, the pointer will change to a Hand and then I can open the list with clicking but just in that case and it happends rare that i can focus the mouse pointer on that area, it's like a small dot on the whole ComboBox.

And the Only code I am using for this ComboBox is, EDITED:

```
public class ChildElement extends OgsAbstractForm<Child> {

    @Inject
    ChildFacade childFacade;

    ComboBox cbChild=new ComboBox();
    HorizontalLayout mainLayout=new MHorizontalLayout();

@Override
protected Component createContent() {

    List<Child> children=new ArrayList<Child>();
    children.addAll(childFacade.findAll());

    for(int i=0;i<children.size();i++){
        cbChild.addItem(children.get(i).getName());
    }

    cbChild.select(children.get(0).getName());

    cbChild.setFilteringMode(FilteringMode.CONTAINS);


    mainLayout.addComponent(cbChild);
    return mainLayout;
}

}
```

And then I'm using this element in a View like below,

```
public class OGSVertragView extends CssLayout implements View{

@Inject
ChildElement childElement;

VerticalLayout main=new VerticalLayout();

@PostConstruct
void init() {

    main.addComponent(childElement);

    addComponents(main);

}
}
```

It would be really nice, when someone could somehow give me a clue or helps me.

Best Regards!

Comment: What is `cbKinder`?

Comment: Sorry, I changed the Elements name from German to English and forgot that one :D @Shirkam

Comment: Which version of Vaadin are you using?

Comment: I'm using Vaadin version 7.7.6

Comment: Please check if you are importing proper **ComboBox** (from `com.vaadin.ui`)

Comment: `import com.vaadin.ui.ComboBox;` yes

Comment: Please attach piece of code where you are adding `ComboBox` to some layout and specify structure of your layouts

Comment: @avix I changed the Code again, It's how I use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks for me like your `ComboBox` doesn't have enough space.
Try setting `mainLayout`height like 200-300 px, and make sure your `VerticalLayout main` will give enough space to `mainLayout. 
Also try adding:

```
cbChild.setImmediate(true);
```

[+ Small tip about initializing variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918578/should-i-initialize-variable-within-constructor-or-outside-constructor)

Comment: Thanks alot! It wasn'T `cbChild.setImmediate(true);` but the width, cbChild had a Width size as 100% and also its parent layout.

Comment: I just changed the width instead of 100% to 100px and it works.

Comment: but how can I do it with percentage instead of pixel? Any Idea?

Comment: Setting width/height to 100% means that you use all available space from parent layout. So in `OGSVertragView` you can make CssLayout full sized, like this: `super.setSizeFull();`. And also take care of `VerticalLayout main` size.