# Where to construct an object

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Instance variable initialization in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994218/instance-variable-initialization-in-java)

Hello, can someone tell me what the difference / pros or cons of creating an object with the declaration of the class instance vars ie..

```
public class ClassName{
    Object o = new Object();
}
```

to in the contructor

```
public class ClassName{ 
    Object o;
    public ClassName(){
        o = new Object();
    }
}
```

thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918578/should-i-initialize-variable-within-constructor-or-outside-constructor

Answer (score 1):

Well in the upper case there's always an object made if the class is loaded, inthe lower case you're only create the object if the class is instantiated.

I guess the second way is always the way to go if you don't make the field o static.

Answer (score 0):

In your case it is effectively the same.

The difference would be if

1. there were other fields that depend on field "o" or
2. there were other Constructors

Answer (score 0):

I usually construct it at the declaration if it's a "trivial" default-constructor thing. I put it in the constructor if

- I need different initializations for different constructors (obviously)
- The initialization depends on some argument of the constructor (obviously)
- The initialization of the field requires any work, such as getting the value from some where else.

As always when there is no semantical difference, rule of thumb is: Go for the alternative that you find **most readable**.