# Initializing with @BeforeClass vs eager initialization in java

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, initialization, testng

I am using spring with dependency injection and came across this puzzling piece of code in my TestNG class and want to clear my head around this issue

I have this below code

```
public class myBase {

    @Autowired @Lazy @Qualifier("someInstanceA")
    protected SomeClass someInstanceA;
.
.
}

public class myTestB extends myBase {
    private String varB = someInstanceA.getVarB();

    @Test
    .
    .
}
```

This above code gave me a NullPointerException at line

```
 private String varB = someInstanceA.getVarB();
```

But when I do this below

```
 public class myTestB extends myBase {
    private String varB;

    @BeforeClass
    private void getVarB() {
        varB = someInstanceA.getVarB();
    }

    @Test
    .
    .
}
```

The tests ran fine. I read that BeforeClass is like a default constructor and eager initialization is similar to initializing a variable using a default constructor. What am I missing here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6335975/autowired-bean-is-null-when-referenced-in-the-constructor-of-another-bean

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15627792/order-in-which-fields-in-a-bean-are-initialized

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer : Bean injection happens after creation of instances of your class.

Since in the creation of `myTestB` (which should start with an uppercase, by the way), you call `getVarB` on `someInstanceA` which is not yet injected, you get a `NullPointerException`.

The second case works because `@BeforeClass` run one time before first test run, after object creation. Thus when calling `someInstanceA#getVarB` in `getVarB` method, `someInstanceA` is already autowired and not null.