# Having a little trouble understanding objects (Java)

Tags: java, object

I am trying to understand the difference between:

```
public class GuessGame {
Player p1;
Player p2;
Player p3;
```

and

```
public void startGame() {
p1 = new Player();
p2 = new Player();
p3 = new Player();
```

Basically, what do these both do in the program? I understand that the startGame method is for creating objects, but what is the first part of the program for?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18927607/instance-variable-declaration-and-instantiation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First part is calling **declaration of object**.

**Declarations** simply notify the compiler that you will be using name to refer to a variable whose type is type. Declarations do not instantiate objects. To instantiate a `Player` object, or any other object, use the new operator.

The second part is called **Instantiating an Object**

The `new` operator instantiates a new object by allocating memory for it. new requires a single argument: a constructor method for the object to be created. The constructor method is responsible for initializing the new object.

You can check [official java tutorial on object creation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html) for more info. 
Or [here](http://www.lysator.liu.se/java/progGuide/java/anatomy/creating.html).

Answer (score 1):

You declared your variables `p1,p2,p3` of type `Player` at instance level and initializing all of them in `startGame()` method.

Comment: And type player comes from the player class. Correct?

Comment: @StephenPeterWisniewski Yes. True. Type I mean is Class only.

Answer (score 1):

The first part declares that you have three `Player` objects available for use in the class. In your `startGame()` method, you're initialising the `Player` objects.

Answer (score 0):

Java is fully Object oriented language. Check this out: [Object-oriented programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming)

For Java syntax take look at this: [Java - Object & Classes](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_object_classes.htm)