# Properties of pre-constructor initialized variable in java

Tags: java

In Java, programming variables can be initialized before calling a constructor.

```
public class StockGraph extends JPanel {

    public boolean runUpdates = true;
    double TickMarks = 18;
    double MiddleTick = TickMarks / 2;
    double PriceInterval = 5;

    double StockMaximum;
    double StockMinimum;

    Random testStockValue;

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.000");

    LinearEquation StockPriceY;

    public StockGraph(int AreaInterval, int Time, int StockID) {

    }
}
```

What are the properties of these variables?

Does `MiddleTick` dynamically change when `TickMarks` change?
When do these variables get initialized?

In particular, `public boolean runUpdates = true;`. As no initialization is needed because one can call `StockGraph.runUpdates` to access the variable?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994218/should-i-instantiate-instance-variables-on-declaration-or-in-the-constructor probably the same question

Comment: You cannot call `StockGraph.runUpdates` directly without first creating an instance of StockGraph because this field is not static.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What are the properties of these variables?

These are instance variables which are assigned a default value.

> Does MiddleTick dynamically change when TickMarks change? When do
>   these variables get initialized?

No `MiddleTick` will use `TickMarks` which is available at `MiddleTick` initialisation time i.e at instance creation time.

> in particular public boolean runUpdates = true; As no initialization
>   is needed because one can call StockGraph.runUpdates to access the
>   variable?

`runUpdates` cannot be directly accessible(StockGraph.runUpdates ) without an instance as it not an instance field and not a static field.

There are different ways to initialise fields in java, depending on the need and code readability. This article throws some light on this:

[Initializing Fields in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html)

Answer (score 5):

Those variables are not initialized prior to calling the constructor, instead they are copied into the constructor(s) immediately after the call to `super()`. The Java Tutorials, [Intializing Fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) says (in part),

> The Java compiler copies initializer blocks into every constructor. Therefore, this approach can be used to share a block of code between multiple constructors.