# java where to allocate memory for member data?. in class itself or constructor?

Tags: java, android

Probably this would be the very most basic question in Java. I want to tell you that i am basically from c background. Please bear with me.

I have a class and would like to have mHTable of type Hasbtable.

**Question:**

Where do i allocate memory for mHTable ? In the class definition or constructor?. Both seems to be working.

Case 1:

```
public class SampleClass
{
    Hashtable<Integer, Integer> mHTble = new Hashtable<Integer, Integer>();

}
```

Or

```
 public class SampleClass
{
  public SampleClass()
  {
     mHTble = new Hashtable<Integer, Integer>();
   }
}
```

I am trying this in Android.

Comment: Memory allocation may not be the right expression, Java isn't such a low-level language as C, and you don't allocate memory by yourself.

Comment: They're identical: [Should I instantiate variables on declaration or in the constructor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994218/should-i-instantiate-instance-variables-on-declaration-or-in-the-constructor)

Comment: Both are valid. depends on ya logic and usage.

Comment: There's hardly any difference. You also could use an instance block { mHTble = new Hashtable<Integer, Integer>(); } Java will always  create mHTable on the heap. In fact, objects (unlike in C/C++) are never created on the stack. Btw, a HashTable is legacy code and these days, either a HashMap or ConcurrentHashMap (thread safe) are preferred.

Comment: This is going too deep, but to correct @dsp_user, the objects *can* be created on stack - look up "escape analysis". But to sum up: it shouldn't matter for most of the cases. :)

Comment: Yes (thank you pointing that out), but only the Java compiler can make this change (in some cases), so it's really not something the programmer has control over. :)

Answer (score 0):

It generally doesn't matter. Use the version you fill comfortable with. If you have many constructors, you might prefer the direct field initialization.

As a guideline, if you don't want to change the reference (i.e. the `mHTble` variable, not the hashtable entries themselves), make it final; then you don't forget to initialize it (compiler will tell you so) and you save yourself from `NullPointerException`s

```
public class SampleClass
{
  private final Hashtable<Integer, Integer> mHTble;

  public SampleClass()
  {
     mHTble = new Hashtable<>();
   }
}
```