# Java declaring private member variables

Tags: java

I was studying in a book and here is the example:

```
public class SimpleGeometricObject {
private String color = "white";
...
```

I've always been taught that we can't give a value to a member variable if its not in a constructor or in a setter. This example from the book, is it a good example? Can we do that? Is that a style problem?

Thanks

Comment: "I've always been taught that we can't give a value to a member variable if its not in a constructor or in a setter." . that's absolutely false.

Comment: It's perfectly valid code.

Comment: Where on earth did you learn or were you 'taught' this nonsense?

Comment: Technically, the assignment is *copied* into **every** constructor (or the *default* constructor if you don't provide one).

Comment: I see... I learned coding using C++, and my professor absolutely told us not to do this way.

Comment: Did your professor say why?  It seems to me like a bizarre thing for them to teach you.

Comment: I'm learning java on my own. The only formal school training was in c++ that's why I was confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can initialize the variable either inside the constructor or outside, both have their benefits and drawbacks. There are a few reasons as explained in the following threads:

- [Should I initialize variable within constructor or outside constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918578/should-i-initialize-variable-within-constructor-or-outside-constructor)
- [Should I instantiate instance variables on declaration or in the constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994218/should-i-instantiate-instance-variables-on-declaration-or-in-the-constructor)

Comment: You can *initialize* the variable either inside or outside the constructor.

Comment: Yeah, I've fixed that.