# why constructor use, why not always use simple initialization of variables?

Tags: java

I have searched about this lot and get this answer on stack overflow
[given answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1994218/6499408)

- **That states that we can use both constructor and simple initialization**

But I want Answer of this

- **but why use constructor initialization  if it automatically done by compiler !**

Comment: I don't understand what is still not clear to you after reading that question and answer.

Comment: Simplest answer to assign them default values for example int type variables always assigned to 0 and if you want default should be 1, When you initialise instance variables in constructor like string with ""(Empty String) you got advantage i.e. you don't have to care about null pointers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Simple definition of constructor:**

Special methods that initialize an object of a class. Always and only used together with the `new` keyword to create an instance of a class.

1. Has the same name as the name of the class.
2. Can take one or more arguments.
3. Has no return value, not even void.
4. Default constructor takes no parameters.
5. More than one constructor exist (method overloading).

> but why use constructor initialization if it automatically done by
>   compiler !

**Constructors initialize by the compiler (default constructor) if you have not implemented a constructor.**

So why do we need to implement a constructor?

- Its job is to tell all of the local variables their initial values,
  and possibly to start off another method within the class to do
  something more towards the purpose of the class.
- Depends on what data you have, i.e. what is available.
- Different ways of creating an object.
- All class variables have to be initialized with the constructor.

As a example:

- Consider the `Rectangle` class in the `java.awt` package which provides several different constructors, all named `Rectangle()`, but each with a different number of arguments, or different types of arguments from which the new `Rectangle` object will get its initial state. Here are the constructor signatures from the [`java.awt.Rectangle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html) class:
- `public Rectangle()`
- `public Rectangle(int width, int height)`
- `public Rectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height)`
- `public Rectangle(Dimension size)`
- `public Rectangle(Point location)`
- `public Rectangle(Point location, Dimension size)`
- `public Rectangle(Rectangle r)`

---

What if your member variables are `private` (security reasons)? If you do not want to give other classes to handle member variables, you have to use getters and setters, but in the first place, you can initialize it with a constructor, then you can change it using getters and setters later on when you need to change/update it.

Answer (score 1):

To create a new object,we have to run the constructor.If we create default  constructor  compiler  automatically  add default  constructor.But when we want to run paramaetrized constructor we have to define in the class..