# How do I create a public default constructor and an overloaded constructor?

Tags: java, constructor, interface

I am extremely new to Java and coding in general. I am working on a project where I have created two interfaces and am now creating a concrete class named VehicleChassis that implements my Chassis interface. First, I created a String named chassisName instance variable. Now, I need to create a default constructor and overloaded constructor with the following value - A String with a parameter value of chassisName. I have searched the Internet on how to do both, but I am so confused. Help!

Below is the code I have so far.

```
public abstract class VehicleChassis implements Chassis{
public String chassisName;
}
```

Comment: [This link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) from Oracle's tutorials might help you.

Comment: please show more context and code. What is `Chassis`, why is it an interface and not a class with members? How do you want to create an instance of `VehicleChassis`, what is the subclass supposed to look like?

Comment: I am working on a project for a class and the instructions start off with creating a Chassis interface. Then, it asked me to create an Engine interface. Now, it is asking me to create a concrete class named VehicleChassis... To be completely honest, I really don't know what I am doing.

Comment: Note that if you're using multiple constructors, you usually want to chain them to one main constructor that does all the work (setting fields etc.). Some examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17171012 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285177

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean this?

```
public abstract class VehicleChassis implements Chassis{
    public String chassisName;
    VehicleChassis() {
        chassisName = "name";
    }
    VehicleChassis(final String chassisName) {
        this.chassisName = chassisName;
    }
}
```

You won't be able to instantiate this `VehicleChassis` because you've declared it as abstract. You can use the constructors if you extend this class, though. Consider declaring the constructors protected if that's what you intend to do.

Comment: This helped! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you arre not implement all the methods in `Chassis` keep `VehicleChassis` as `abstract`.

You can overload constructor as many as you want.

```
public String chassisName;
public VehicleChassis() {
    chassisName = "No";
}
public VehicleChassis(String chassisName) {
    this.chassisName = chassisName;
}
```

If you have another instance variable:

```
public VehicleChassis(String chassisName, int price) {
    this.chassisName = chassisName;
    this.price = price;
}
```

For more about [constructor overloading read this question answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44278015/why-constructor-use-why-not-always-use-simple-initialization-of-variables/44278165#44278165).

Comment: Thank you for sharing. It definitely helped me understand this concept better!

Answer (score 0):

You can create constructor as below.If the instance variable is more and all are not mandatory then you can use builder pattern to build your object step by step.

```
 public class VehicleChassis implements Chassis {
        public String chassisName;

        public VehicleChassis() {
            // some code
        }

        public VehicleChassis(String chassisName) {
            this.chassisName = chassisName;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing. I appreciate it!

Answer (score -3):

A class which is labelled as abstract could not be instantiate directly. so we don't need to create constructor and overloaded constructor.

Comment: They do have a use: you can call them from a subclass.

Comment: The only reason I added abstract is the IDE I am using showed an error and 'encouraged' me to use the word abstract.

Comment: @ElizabethIsgro I suspect whatever methods were declared in the Chassis interface were missing. Make sure they match exactly. Often an IDE can add these automatically.

Comment: Please refrain from adding excessive bold/quote formatting to your ordinary paragraph text. That will reduce the amount of repair work needed from volunteer editors in the future. Thank you.