# Should I keep field initialization in the declaration of a superclass when subclasses initialize in the constructor?

Tags: java

Based on the answers from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918578/should-i-initialize-variable-within-constructor-or-outside-constructor/3919225?noredirect=1#comment80251780_3919225), given that I have a class with fields initialized on the declaration, what should I do when I extend that class and need the subclass to have a different default value?

Should I assign the new default value in the constructor of the subclass and keep the assignment in the declaration for the superclass?:

```
public class Bird {
    private boolean flight = true;
}

public class Penguin extends Bird {
    public Penguin() {
        flight = false;
    }
}
```

Or should I refactor so that both classes initialize fields in the constructor?

From the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994218/should-i-instantiate-instance-variables-on-declaration-or-in-the-constructor) it looks like there are no significant technical differences, so this is a question about semantics.

Comment: Currently that code wouldn't even compile, as `Penguin` doesn't have access to `Bird`. Personally I'd provide a protected constructor in `Bird` that lets the subclass provide a value for `flight` - that way you can keep the field private and make it final too.

Comment: flight is private in child class.

Comment: Despite the visibility issue, it would see this as opinion based. Personally, I prefere to define general / default values in the parent `Bird`. But all child class would overwrite them with their own needed values. So the values in parent are just to be there as default or fallback, if I or someone else forgets to set a value in the child.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First the differences between the two cases.

For an *immutable* property (the most restrictive - nice - case):

```
public class Bird {
    public final boolean flight;

    public Bird() {
        this(true);
    }

    protected Bird(boolean flight) {
        this.flight = flight();
    }
}

public class Penguin extends Bird {
    public Penguin() {
        super(false);
    }
}
```

For a more liberal, dynamic usage:

```
public class Bird {
    protected boolean flight = true;
    public boolean hasFligth() {
        return flight;
    }
}

public class Penguin extends Bird {
    public Penguin() {
        flight = false;
    }
}
```

However `flight` might be considered not a property on every individual Bird / Penguin object: it is a property of the class (Penguin, Ostrich, ...). A kind of strategy pattern, or:

```
Map<Class<Bird>, Boolean>
Set<Class<Bird>> // better
```

Situated at the other side, in a class Flight.

Answer (score 1):

If you design your superclass for extension and want to allow certain field to be initializable to another value, you should probably expose this via constructor parameter:

```
public class Bird {
    private final boolean flight = true;
    public Bird() {
        this(true);
    }
    public Bird(boolean flight) {
        this.fligjt = flight;
    }
    public boolean isFlight() {
        return this.flight;
    }
}

public class Penguin extends Bird {
    public Penguin() {
        super(false);
    }
}
```