# Why should LiveData objects in ViewModel be instantiated during declaration?

Tags: java, android, android-architecture-components

Please consider the following code from [Google's Architecture Components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata.html) tutorial:

```
class MyViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private final PostalCodeRepository repository;
    private final MutableLiveData<String> addressInput = new MutableLiveData();
    public final LiveData<String> postalCode =
            Transformations.switchMap(addressInput, (address) -> {
                return repository.getPostCode(address);
             });

  public MyViewModel(PostalCodeRepository repository) {
      this.repository = repository
  }

  private void setInput(String address) {
      addressInput.setValue(address);
  }
}
```

Please note that `LiveData` objects are instantiated during declaration.

From what I can tell from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994218/should-i-instantiate-instance-variables-on-declaration-or-in-the-constructor), there is very little difference difference between instantiating them during declaration or inside of a constrictor. Yet, from what I understand, there is a possibility of having `NPE`s or having stale references when `LiveData` objects are instantiated through a constructer, so Googles' recommendation is to instantiate them during declaration.

My *hunch* is that it may have something to do with creating `ViewModel` objects through reflection, however I have been unable to find how exactly it could effect creation of those objects.

Why should `LiveData` objects be instantiated during declaration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please consider the following code from Google's Architecture Components tutorial:

That is not a tutorial. It is a reference with some code snippets, many of which will not compile, as they are there to illustrate syntax and call structure, not actually run.

> Please note that LiveData objects are instantiated during declaration.

That is what the person who wrote that code snippet elected to do.

> so Googles' recommendation is to instantiate them during declaration.

Google makes no such recommendation. The code snippet that you cite is an *example*, nothing more.

> Why should LiveData objects be instantiated during declaration?

They do not have be fields with initializers. You are welcome to instantiate them in the constructor if you so choose. `ViewModel` has specific rules about constructors (e.g., if you are not providing a factory, it needs to have a zero-argument constructor, or a one-`Application`-argument constructor for `AndroidViewModel`). But, other than that, you can do whatever you want.

It is frequently more concise to use an initializer — where the initializer is an available option — so there may be a *tendency* to use initalizers.